# more values from one table in other table under same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Employers`, with: `ID`, `surname`, `name`, `language_id`.

Other table is Languages, with: `ID`, `language`.

How to put if one employer speak more than one language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove lanugauge_id from  Employers Table and create one new table which contain multi relation between user_id and language_id so you want to take

```
    YOUR NEW TABLE NAME(i.e : user_languages)

    COLUMN NAME :
    --------------------------
    1. id (int,primary_key)

    2. employers_id(int)

    3. language_id(int)

    4. create_time(DateTime)
```

Using this you will enter multiple entries for multiple languages from single user where you want to enter employers table primary key in employers_id and languages table primary key in language_id

Answer (score 1):

You can create an other table with the following fields :

```
ID (int,primary_key)

id_Employers(int)

id_Languages(int)
```

And remove `language_id` from **Employers** table